# How to parse answer from api to dict not list in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing

I study python first month sorry if it is a stupid question).

```
import requests
url='https://api.github.com/repositories?q=language:python&sort=stars'
r=requests.get(url)
print('status code:', r.status_code)
response_dict=r.json()
print(response_dict.keys())
```

But response_dict becomes list not dict type. How can i get dict?
Tried to make `response_dict=dict(r.json())`. Got this error.
"dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 46; 2 is required" Thank you for help.

Comment: And what would you like to have as keys in that dict?

Comment: Please provide the JSON you are expecting to parse with this

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the point of converting the list to a dict? Please provide the current as well as expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your response is a list of dicts. If you wish to extract a single item you can say

```
response_dict=r.json()[0]
```

If you want to change your list into a dictionary, then you could use the 'id' parameter from each item as the key:

```
response = r.json()
response_dict = dict([ (i['id'], i) for i in response])
```

or if you prefer to use the 'name' parameter:

```
response_dict = dict([ (i['name'], i) for i in response ])
```

Answer (score 1):

your `response_dict` is a `list` of 100 `dict`, you can use:

```
response_dict=r.json()[0] # if you want to access the frist dict
print(response_dict.keys())
```

output:

```
dict_keys(['id', 'node_id', 'name', 'full_name', 'private', 'owner', 'html_url', 'description', 'fork', 'url', 'forks_url', 'keys_url', 'collaborators_url', 'teams_url', 'hooks_url', 'issue_events_url', 'events_url', 'assignees_url', 'branches_url', 'tags_url', 'blobs_url', 'git_tags_url', 'git_refs_url', 'trees_url', 'statuses_url', 'languages_url', 'stargazers_url', 'contributors_url', 'subscribers_url', 'subscription_url', 'commits_url', 'git_commits_url', 'comments_url', 'issue_comment_url', 'contents_url', 'compare_url', 'merges_url', 'archive_url', 'downloads_url', 'issues_url', 'pulls_url', 'milestones_url', 'notifications_url', 'labels_url', 'releases_url', 'deployments_url'])
```

the response contains a list with 100 dictionaries

```
len(r.json())
# 100
```